# In a bash shell script, writing a for loop that iterates over string values

Tags: bash, shell-script, for

In bash, I know that it is possible to write a `for` loop in which some loop control variable `i` iterates over specified integers.  For example, I can write a bash shell script that prints the integers between 1 and 10:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..10}
do
 echo $i
done
```

Is it possible to instead iterate over a loop control variable that is a string, if I provide a list of strings?  For example, suppose that I have a string `fname` that represents a file name.  I want to call a set of commands for each file name.  For example, I might want to print the contents of `fname` using a command like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for fname in {"a.txt", "b.txt", "c.txt"}
do
 echo $fname
done
```

In other words, on the first iteration, `fname` should have the value `fname="a.txt"`, while on the second iteration, `fname` should have the value `fname="b.txt"`, and so on.  Unfortunately, it seems that the above syntax is not quite correct.  I would like to obtain the output:

> a.txt
>
> b.txt
>
> c.txt

but when I try the above code, I obtain this output:

> {a.txt,
>
> b.txt,
>
> c.txt}

Can you please help me determine the correct syntax, so that I can iteratively change the value/contents of the variable `fname`?  Thank you for your time.

Comment: Remove the `{}`, you don't need anything to loop over a (space-delimited) list

Comment: @Mat means remove the `{}` _and_ the `,`s. The alternative is to remove the spaces. So either `"a.txt" "b.txt" "c.txt"` or `{"a.txt","b.txt","c.txt"}`. But I prefer `{a..c}.txt` instead.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The correct syntax is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

for fname in a.txt b.txt c.txt
do
  echo $fname
done
```

Comment: Also, assuming an array of names `fnames=( a.txt b.txt c.txt )` you can use the syntax `for f in ${fnames[@]}; do echo $f; done`.

Comment: Is it true that `for fname in a.txt b.txt c.txt` and `for fname in "a.txt" "b.txt" "c.txt"` yield identical results?

Comment: Andrew, yes it is true. They will yield identical results

Comment: Of course you should use `for f in "${fnames[@]}"; do echo $f; done` (with quotes around `${fnames[@]}`) if the `fnames` values might contain whitespace.  And you should use `"$f"`, especially if you're doing anything more sophisticated than `echo` (e.g., `cat` or `cp`). (And even if you're only doing `echo`, you should use `printf` instead.)

Comment: I think @user13742 should be also noted in the answer.

Comment: There's pretty much never a reason to not use double quotes around a variable in bash. If you want a string to split on IFS, you should probably be using an array instead.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you should just do...

```
printf %s.txt\\n a b c
```

Comment: I like this even though the OP likely had something in mind to do other than echo before he was done.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by user13742 in the [comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47557/in-a-bash-shell-script-writing-a-for-loop-that-iterates-over-string-values/404126#comment66164_47560), we can make use of arrays in `bash` and `ksh`:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

files_list=( "a.txt" "b.txt" "c and space.txt" )

for i in "${files_list[@]}"
do
    echo "$i"
    # do something else here,maybe
done
```

And works as so:

```
$ ./iterate_files_array.sh                                                      
a.txt
b.txt
c and space.txt
```

However, some shells such as `dash` ( `/bin/sh` on Ubuntu ) don't support arrays. In such case we could resort to using here-document structure: `<<`

```
#!/bin/sh

while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo "$line"
done << EOL
one.txt
two.txt
with space.txt
EOL
```