# In a bash script, using the conditional "or" in an "if" statement

Tags: bash, shell-script

This question is a sequel of sorts to my [earlier question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47557/in-a-bash-shell-script-writing-a-for-loop-that-iterates-over-string-values).  The users on this site kindly helped me determine how to write a bash `for` loop that iterates over string values.  For example, suppose that a loop control variable `fname` iterates over the strings `"a.txt" "b.txt" "c.txt"`.  I would like to `echo` "yes!" when `fname` has the value `"a.txt"` or `"c.txt"`, and `echo` "no!" otherwise.  I have tried the following bash shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for fname in "a.txt" "b.txt" "c.txt"
do
  echo $fname
  if [ "$fname" = "a.txt" ] | [ "$fname" = "c.txt" ]; then
    echo "yes!"
  else
    echo "no!"
  fi
done
```

I obtain the output:

> a.txt
>
> no!
>
> b.txt
>
> no!
>
> c.txt
>
> yes!

Why does the `if` statement apparently yield true when `fname` has the value `"a.txt"`?  Have I used `|` incorrectly?

Comment: In bash, 'or' operator is '||' (C style).

Comment: You can also use `-o` within the same `[ ]`.

Comment: @Thor I'd prefer `||` and separate `[ ]` over `-o` for portability simply because `[` is not guaranteed to support more than 4 arguments.  Of course if the target language is `bash`, no one should be using `[` anyways because `bash`'s `[[` is superior in many ways.

Comment: @jw013 Thanks. Does this mean that I should be using `if [[ "$fname" = "a.txt" ]] || [[ "$fname" = "c.txt" ]]` rather than `if [ "$fname" = "a.txt" ] || [ "$fname" = "c.txt" ]`?

Comment: @Andrew That is correct, if as you are declaring the shebang as `bash`, as you are already doing.  One advantage of `[[` is that it doesn't do word splitting (special case) so `[[ $unquoted_var = string ]]` is safe.

Comment: `The XSI extensions specifying the -a and -o binary primaries and the '(' and ')' operators have been marked obsolescent.` and should not be used.

Comment: One huge disadvantage of `[[` (IMO, a complete show stopper) is that it does not produce reasonable error messages, but happily returns truthiness with no error message to statements like `[[ $a -eq 0 ]]` when $a is not an integer value.  In other words, if the target language is bash, no one should be using `[[` at all.

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate!): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408493/

Answer (score 868, accepted):

If you want to say `OR` use double pipe (`||`).

```
if [ "$fname" = "a.txt" ] || [ "$fname" = "c.txt" ]
```

(The original OP code using `|` was simply piping the output of the left side to the right side, in the same way any ordinary pipe works.)

---

After many years of comments and misunderstanding, allow me to clarify.

To do `OR` you use `||`.

Whether you use `[` or `[[` or `test` or `((` all depends on what you need on a case by case basis. It's wrong to say that one of those is preferred in all cases. Sometimes `[` is right and `[[` is wrong. But that's not what the question was. OP asked why `|` didn't work. The answer is because it should be `||` instead.

Comment: Furthermore, `||` doesn't do a standard logic "OR" - it short-circuits, and the second command is run only if the first fails.

Comment: @holdenweb I'm pretty sure most modern optimized languages work the same way. No need to spend CPU cycles evaluating the second condition of `OR` if the first condition evaluates true.

Comment: I thought bash liked `==` but after seeing this answer, I decided to look it up.  Apparently, "it can be used but isn't standard".  I thought I'd put this here for others if your curious: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2237103

Comment: This is what the `test` man page recommends too

Comment: You can also use double bracket tests - `if [[ "$fname" = "a.txt" ]] || [[ "$fname" = "c.txt" ]]` (If you want or need to have the extra functionality associated with `[[ ]]`).

Comment: @bahamat, you should use `=` instead of `==` in `[...]`, it's the standard comparison operator. Bash does support `==` too, but not all shells do.

Comment: There is no need to wrap every expression in brackets which is slower in addition to adding more clutter.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that for AND use `&&` instead of `||`.

Comment: I think @AnandShanbhag answer is better than this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47584/in-a-bash-script-using-the-conditional-or-in-an-if-statement/586897#586897

Comment: @Massimo Since `[` is the same thing as `test`, it's literally the same answer.

Comment: @bahamat 1) not all the readers know 2) the simplest form to read and remember is *test*

Comment: I disagree with your assertion, but it's beside the point anyway. The question was why `|` doesn't work. The answer is because it's supposed to be `||`. Using `test` vs `[` is entirely irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Completely disagree with Massimo too, `test` is horribly UNintuitive and brackets read much easier. Also easier when switching between programming languages.

Comment: How to correctly negate it? Is `if ! [ "$fname" = "a.txt" ] || [ "$fname" = "c.txt" ]` correct?

Comment: @pmor Yes, but you need to negate each expression independently. Your expression would be "if $fname is anything other than a.txt, or is c.txt", which doesn't make much sense. If you want not A and not B then it's `if ! [[ A ]] && ! [[ B ]]; then ...`. And remember that "not A OR not B" is not the same thing as "not A AND not B".

Comment: does `if [ -n "$NEW_FLAGNAME" ] || [ -n "$LEGACY_FLAGNAME"]` work?

Comment: I forget space after `"$LEGACY_FLAGNAME"`. `if [ -n "$NEW_FLAGNAME" ] || [ -n "$LEGACY_FLAGNAME" ]; then echo enabled; else echo disabled; fi` works as needed(`;` can be replaced with newlines)

Answer (score 278):

The accepted answer is good but since you're using bash I'll add the bash solution:

```
if [[ "$fname" == "a.txt" || "$fname" == "c.txt" ]]; then
```

This is documented in the bash reference manual [3.2.4.2 Conditional Constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Compound-Commands)

> expression1 && expression2
>
> > True if both expression1 and expression2 are true.
>
> expression1 || expression2
>
> > True if either expression1 or expression2 is true.
>
> The && and || operators do not evaluate expression2 if the value of expression1 is sufficient to determine the return value of the entire conditional expression.

Comment: +1 Agree this is the better answer (vs the "accepted" answer). Careful readers should note that the `||` (or `&&`) are _inside_ the conditional, which in this case necessarily uses `[[...]]` and not `[...]` (i.e., it's not the shell's "or"/"and"). I'll only add that `[[ ... ]]` is not only more useful, supports more options (eg `||`, `&&`, `<`, `>`) but also "safer" than older `[ ...]` ;  the old `-a` and `-o` from the single-bracket syntax is supported, too, and as expected, operators "and" take precedence over "or".  http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html#DBLBRACKETS

Comment: I think @AnandShanbhag answer is better than this. Why spend neurons to bother about single or double brackets? C'mon, let do a favor to your readers: use *test*

Comment: For the && operator is this true?  "The && and || operators do not evaluate expression2 if the value of expression1 is sufficient to determine the return value of the entire conditional expression."  I understand the || case, but does anyone know of an example with the && case where you wouldn't need to evaluate expression2?  It doesn't seem logically possible, but I'm probably missing or misunderstanding something.

Comment: @jbobbins: If expression1 is false there is no need to evaluate expression2.

Comment: Wow, that's embarrassing... I guess my brain was locked into true mode. ;(  Maybe it's time to retire :D

Answer (score 8):

You can also use OR condition like this

```
if test "$fname" = "a.txt" || test "$fname" = "c.txt"
```

Comment: This is fundamentally the same as the accepted answer (and several comments) but more characters and (IMHO) less readable.

Comment: It is easier to read *test* than brackets. Why make the code more cryptic than necessary?

Comment: That is your subjective opinion. Mine is that brackets are easier to read. None of our opinions is "correct", just saying.

Comment: Massimo, you’re replying under every answer stating that you think `test` is more convenient, yet nobody is upvoting these comments. How much cue do you need? You might think your way is best, but I think most people disagree. Sorry :)

Comment: @Massimo "more readable" is a subjective opinion. But `[]` and `[[]]` are clearly more idiomatic.

Comment: This is educational for those who are not aware that [ (and [[ ) is a shortcut alias for /bin/test .

Answer (score 2):

You can use or condition like this

```
 if [ "$fname" = "a.txt" -o "$fname" = "c.txt" ]
```

Comment: Yes you can, but using `-o` for "or" is [marked as obsolete in the POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html), as is using `-a` for "and". New code should not use `-o` or `-a`.

Comment: It also makes for unreliable code as the `[` command is not always able to parse its arguments correctly when given more than 4 arguments (beside `[` and `]`). Try for instance with `fname='!'` with the `[` builtin of the `bash`  shell.