# Simplify sequence of bash conditions

Tags: bash

I have these bash sequence of commands and would like to simplify it.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
  [[ "$fl" == *"img"* ]] && mv "$flimg" "$out"
  [[ "$fl" == *"png"* ]] && mv "$flimg" "$out"
  [[ "$fl" == *"jpg"* ]] && mv "$flimg" "$out"
  [[ "$fl" == *"tif"* ]] && mv "$flimg" "$out"
```

Comment: What are `$fl` and `$flimg`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In a bash script, using the conditional "or" in an "if" statement](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47584/in-a-bash-script-using-the-conditional-or-in-an-if-statement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bash supports extended regular expression and you could do all checks in one, like:

```
[[ $file =~ (img|png|jpg|tif) ]] && echo do-something
```

to check if the variable *file* contains any one of those given strings (note that I used [`=~` operator](/q/340440/72456) for the regex matching).

Comment: I want to remove some files in the end using `rm` but do not want it to use some user alias for it.  What can I do?

Comment: @khin see [How can I run original command that aliased with same name?](https://askubuntu.com/q/525231/283843); BTW, [aliases are not available within a bash scripts or you can enable it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1496/72456). In case you have a separate and new question please first do some research and please take a look at [How do I ask a good question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the regex, a less elegant method would be to *combine the conditionals* by using `OR` - which, in Bash, is a double pipe (`||`):

```
[[ "$fl" == *"img"* || "$fl" == *"png"* || "$fl" == *"jpg"* || "$fl" == *"tif"* ]] && mv "$flimg" "$out"
```

Double pipe would also work in Bourne or Korn shell - using just single braces (`[]`) and changing `==` to `=` (for Bourne only), for example

```
[ "$fl" = *"img"* || "$fl" = *"png"* || "$fl" = *"jpg"* || "$fl" = *"tif"* ] && mv "$flimg" "$out"
```

Comment: What is this kind of construct `[[ "$fl" == *"img"* ]]` called, with the wildcard thing?

Comment: It is called a [*conditional*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html), `[[]]` (or `[]`) is equivalent to `test`. The `*` is [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)).

Comment: See also [How to compare strings in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2237080/4424636) - there are plenty of useful examples

Comment: `[[ ... ]]` is absolutely not equivalent to `[ ... ]` or `test`.  Just try `[[ * = * ]] && echo ok` and `[ * = * ] && echo ok` and `test * = * && echo ok` in a directory with two or more files in it.

Comment: "Globbing" is when you use a shell pattern to generate a list of filenames. `*` is a shell pattern.  It is a "globbing pattern" when used to generate a list of filenames. In your code, you don't use it as a globbing pattern since you are not doing any globbing. You are doing a pattern match.  The `==` operator is the pattern matching operator in `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

Using POSIX standard `sh` syntax, which would also be valid in `bash`, you could use a `case` statement here:

```bsh
case $fl in
    *img*|*jpg*|*png*|*tif*)
        mv -- "$flimg" "$out"
esac
```

or, as a "one-liner",

```bsh
case $fl in (*img*|*jpg*|*png*|*tif*) mv -- "$flimg" "$out"; esac
```

If you enable the `extglob` shell option with `shopt -s extglob`, you may also use

```bsh
[[ $fl == *@(img|jpg|png|tif)* ]] && mv -- "$flimg" "$out"
```

---

If you only want to test a filename suffix after the last dot in the filename in `$fl`:

```bsh
case ${fl##*.} in (img|jpg|png|tif) mv -- "$flimg" "$out"; esac
```

or, after `shopt -s extglob`,

```
[[ ${fl##*.} == @(img|jpg|png|tif) ]] && mv -- "$flimg" "$out"
```

The standard expansion `${variable##pattern}` removes the longest prefix string from `$variable` that matches `pattern`.  Using `*.` as the pattern means deleting everything up to and including the last dot in the value.

Note at that all pattern matches done in this answer are by means of shell patterns, not regular expressions.